# Where can I find something suitably grisly?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

In the dance hall on the ground floor, (north of the *What’s Your Poison* bar), there is a ghost who pickpockets Aurum Runes at 5:30.

If you talk to him afterwards, he says:

> I found something very interesting on a large gentleman who passed through here! [...]
>
> If you can offer me something **suitably grisly** for my costume, I will trade you whatever I found. Deal?

Where can I find something suitably grisly to trade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Give the ghost the Sated Hungry Charm you used to save Willow Blue.**

1. Go to the first floor and pickup the *Hungry Charm*.
2. Go through the right door and use the *Hungry Charm* on the fishtank on the right side. (received *Fed Hungry Charm*)
3. Go through the right door, then the upper left door, and use the *Fed Hungry Charm* on the fish tank. (received *Sated Hungry Charm*).
4. Return to the dance hall on the ground floor behind the bar.
5. Light the candle to see the ghosts.
6. Wait for the ghost to pickpocket Aurum Runes at 5:30.
7. Talk to the pickpocket ghost to trade the *Sated Hungry Charm* for *Aurum Runes’ invitation*.